# Why new operator hangs my program?

Tags: c++, arduino

I use Arduino but I think this is not Arduino related problem, but I do not understand something.
When I use the following code all works perfectly:

```
#include <Queue.h>

typedef struct strRec {
    int entry1;
    int entry2;
} Rec;

Rec tab[3] = {
    { 700, 7000 },
    { 300, 3000 },
    { 1000, 1000 },

};

Queue q(sizeof(Rec), 2, FIFO);  // Instantiate queue

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(19200);

    unsigned int i;

    for (i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
    {
        Rec rec = tab[i];
        q.push(&rec);
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
    {
        Rec rec;
        if(q.pop(&rec)) {
        Serial.print(rec.entry1);
        Serial.print(" ");
        Serial.println(rec.entry2);
        }
        else {
            Serial.println("No records");
        }
    }

}
```

But when I create an instance using **new** the program hangs after the operator: no operations performerd after it.

```
#include <Queue.h>

typedef struct strRec {
    int entry1;
    int entry2;
} Rec;

Rec tab[3] = {
    { 700, 7000 },
    { 300, 3000 },
    { 1000, 1000 },

};

Queue* q;   

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(19200);

    q = new Queue(sizeof(Rec), 2, FIFO);

    unsigned int i;

    for (i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
    {
        Rec rec = tab[i];
        q->push(&rec);
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
    {
        Rec rec;
        if(q->pop(&rec)) {
        Serial.print(rec.entry1);
        Serial.print(" ");
        Serial.println(rec.entry2);
        }
        else {
            Serial.println("No records");
        }
    }

}
```

But if I do not call any method of Queue class but only create it the code below can be executed

```
Serial.println("some text before"); //this text can be printed
q = new Queue(sizeof(Rec), 2, FIFO);
Serial.println("some text after"); //this text can be printed too
```

if I have method call here, the call hangs program **right after the *new***, but not after method call

```
Serial.println("some text before"); //this text can be printed
q = new Queue(sizeof(Rec), 2, FIFO);
Serial.println("some text after"); //this text can not be printed and the program hangs here
Rec rec = tab[1];
q->push(&rec);
```

I even tried to change *push* method to do nothing but the code hangs.
If I comment the string with free my code works normally, so the problem is here but I do not understad why

```
Queue::Queue(uint16_t size_rec, uint16_t nb_recs, QueueType type, bool overwrite)
{

    rec_nb = nb_recs;
    rec_sz = size_rec;
    impl = type;
    ovw = overwrite;

    if (queue)  { free(queue); }    // If I comment this string it works as I need
    queue = (uint8_t *) malloc(nb_recs * size_rec);

    clean();
}

Queue::~Queue()
{
  free(queue);
}


void Queue::clean(void)
{
    in = 0;
    out = 0;
    cnt = 0;
}
```

Why it happens? What I do not understand?

[Here is the Queue class](http://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/queue)

Comment: Assuming `Queue` has semantics that make those calls safe (usually passing a pointer to a local to store would be bad, but the way the `pop` works (and the way the ctor is defined) makes me think it's just a C-like API that takes a pointer to something that is then copied) .... nothing is wrong with the code.

Comment: Is that a [mcve]?  I can't see the definition of `FIFO`.

Comment: I added the link to the Queue library.

Comment: My guess would be, you have heap corruption bug elsewhere in the program. This piece of code just accidentally happened to fall victim of it when it started using the heap.

Comment: What kind of board is it?

Comment: Arduino Due board

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this line in the constructor:

```
if (queue) { free(queue); } // Free existing data (if any)
```

where `queue` is a data member. You are trying to free a garbage pointer value (that just happened to be non-zero) that you never initialized, thus invoking UB. Why do you believe this needed to be done at all?